# "soap_call__" function returns only last TCP packet in the soap context buffer

Tags: gsoap

I have a problem as I get an answer from the WEB service that is split in many TCP packets.

- Create 'MercuriusService.h'

  ---

1) wsdl2h -o MercuriusService.h -t MRJ_typemap.dat -c ./WSDL/provider/MercuriusService.wsdl

2) Add WS-Security support in "Import" section of MercuriusService.h

```
#import "wsse.h"  // wsse = <http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd>
```

- Generate C code

  ---

3) soapcpp2 -c -C MercuriusService.h

I work in C language and I am client.

- Makefile gSOAP oriented content

  ---

  INCL= commons.h soapH.h soapStub.h MercuriusServiceSoap12.nsmap 
  OBJS=   soapC.o soapClient.o gsoap/stdsoap2.o gsoap/dom.o \
                          gsoap/plugin/mecevp.o gsoap/plugin/threads.o gsoap/plugin/smdevp.o gsoap/plugin/wsseapi.o \
                          commons.o

commons.h and commons.o are part of my program

- Testing the program

  ---

As the reply comes in more than on TCP packet the "soap_call_xxx" function
fills in the soap buffer with only the last packet as can be seen here after :

In TEST.log I found :

```
...
Read 4344 bytes from socket=5/fd=0
Read count=4344 (+4344)
...
Read 999 bytes from socket=5/fd=0
Read count=5343 (+999)
...
```

And in the log of my client I get on "soap_call__xxx" inthe soap buffer :

```
2020-04-03 12:52:27 - TST_MERCURJUS - from commons_request (thread 00000)

000 : X6F X6E X2F X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61  | on/><ns4:Examina
016 : X74 X69 X6F X6E X43 X6F X6D X6D X65 X6E X74 X73 X2F X3E X3C X2F  | tionComments/></
032 : X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X49 X6E X66 X6F X3E X3C X6E X73  | ns4:ExamInfo><ns
048 : X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X49 X6E X66 X6F X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A  | 4:ExamInfo><ns4:
064 : X45 X76 X6F X6C X75 X74 X69 X6F X6E X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E  | EvolutionNumber>
080 : X32 X32 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X76 X6F X6C X75 X74 X69 X6F  | 22</ns4:Evolutio
096 : X6E X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61  | nNumber><ns4:Exa
112 : X6D X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X33 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45  | mNumber>3</ns4:E
128 : X78 X61 X6D X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X52  | xamNumber><ns4:R
144 : X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X31 X3C X2F X6E  | esultNumber>1</n
160 : X73 X34 X3A X52 X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E  | s4:ResultNumber>
176 : X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X44 X61 X74 X65 X3E X32 X30  | <ns4:ExamDate>20
192 : X31 X39 X2D X30 X37 X2D X30 X32 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78  | 19-07-02</ns4:Ex
208 : X61 X6D X44 X61 X74 X65 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D  | amDate><ns4:Exam
224 : X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X54 X79 X70 X65 X3E X4D X3C X2F X6E  | inationType>M</n
240 : X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X54 X79  | s4:ExaminationTy
256 : X70 X65 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74  | pe><ns4:Examinat
272 : X69 X6F X6E X52 X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X3E X34 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34  | ionResult>4</ns4
288 : X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X52 X65 X73 X75  | :ExaminationResu
304 : X6C X74 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X43 X6F X6E X64 X69 X74 X69 X6F  | lt><ns4:Conditio
320 : X6E X61 X6C X52 X65 X69 X6E X73 X74 X61 X74 X65 X6D X65 X6E X74  | nalReinstatement
336 : X44 X75 X72 X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X2F X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45  | Duration/><ns4:E
352 : X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X43 X6F X6D X6D X65 X6E  | xaminationCommen
368 : X74 X73 X2F X3E X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X49 X6E  | ts/></ns4:ExamIn
384 : X66 X6F X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X49 X6E X66 X6F  | fo><ns4:ExamInfo
400 : X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X76 X6F X6C X75 X74 X69 X6F X6E X4E  | ><ns4:EvolutionN
416 : X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X32 X32 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X76  | umber>22</ns4:Ev
432 : X6F X6C X75 X74 X69 X6F X6E X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X3C X6E  | olutionNumber><n
448 : X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X34 X3C  | s4:ExamNumber>4<
464 : X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E  | /ns4:ExamNumber>
480 : X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X52 X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X4E X75 X6D X62 X65  | <ns4:ResultNumbe
496 : X72 X3E X31 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X52 X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X4E  | r>1</ns4:ResultN
512 : X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X44  | umber><ns4:ExamD
528 : X61 X74 X65 X3E X32 X30 X31 X39 X2D X30 X37 X2D X30 X32 X3C X2F  | ate>2019-07-02</
544 : X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X44 X61 X74 X65 X3E X3C X6E X73  | ns4:ExamDate><ns
560 : X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X54 X79 X70  | 4:ExaminationTyp
576 : X65 X3E X53 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61  | e>S</ns4:Examina
592 : X74 X69 X6F X6E X54 X79 X70 X65 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78  | tionType><ns4:Ex
608 : X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X52 X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X3E  | aminationResult>
624 : X34 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69  | 4</ns4:Examinati
640 : X6F X6E X52 X65 X73 X75 X6C X74 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X43 X6F  | onResult><ns4:Co
656 : X6E X64 X69 X74 X69 X6F X6E X61 X6C X52 X65 X69 X6E X73 X74 X61  | nditionalReinsta
672 : X74 X65 X6D X65 X6E X74 X44 X75 X72 X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E X2F X3E  | tementDuration/>
688 : X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X45 X78 X61 X6D X69 X6E X61 X74 X69 X6F X6E  | <ns4:Examination
704 : X43 X6F X6D X6D X65 X6E X74 X73 X2F X3E X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A  | Comments/></ns4:
720 : X45 X78 X61 X6D X49 X6E X66 X6F X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X50 X56  | ExamInfo><ns4:PV
736 : X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X41 X4E X2F X41 X2F X39 X30 X2F X4C  | Number>AN/A/90/L
752 : X42 X2F X34 X39 X38 X33 X35 X30 X2F X32 X30 X31 X38 X3C X2F X6E  | B/498350/2018</n
768 : X73 X34 X3A X50 X56 X4E X75 X6D X62 X65 X72 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34  | s4:PVNumber><ns4
784 : X3A X4C X69 X66 X65 X4C X6F X6E X67 X49 X6E X64 X69 X63 X61 X74  | :LifeLongIndicat
800 : X6F X72 X3E X30 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X4C X69 X66 X65 X4C X6F  | or>0</ns4:LifeLo
816 : X6E X67 X49 X6E X64 X69 X63 X61 X74 X6F X72 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34  | ngIndicator><ns4
832 : X3A X44 X65 X73 X63 X72 X69 X70 X74 X69 X6F X6E X43 X6F X64 X65  | :DescriptionCode
848 : X3E X30 X34 X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X44 X65 X73 X63 X72 X69 X70  | >04</ns4:Descrip
864 : X74 X69 X6F X6E X43 X6F X64 X65 X3E X3C X6E X73 X34 X3A X41 X70  | tionCode><ns4:Ap
880 : X70 X65 X61 X6C X49 X6E X64 X69 X63 X61 X74 X6F X72 X3E X30 X3C  | pealIndicator>0<
896 : X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X41 X70 X70 X65 X61 X6C X49 X6E X64 X69 X63  | /ns4:AppealIndic
912 : X61 X74 X6F X72 X3E X3C X2F X6E X73 X34 X3A X69 X6E X66 X72 X61  | ator></ns4:infra
928 : X63 X74 X69 X6F X6E X49 X6E X66 X6F X3E X3C X2F X6E X73 X33 X3A  | ctionInfo></ns3:
944 : X69 X6E X66 X6F X3E X3C X2F X6E X73 X33 X3A X46 X69 X6E X64 X49  | info></ns3:FindI
960 : X6E X66 X6F X52 X65 X73 X70 X6F X6E X73 X65 X3E X3C X2F X65 X6E  | nfoResponse></en
976 : X76 X3A X42 X6F X64 X79 X3E X3C X2F X73 X6F X61 X70 X3A X45 X6E  | v:Body></soap:En
992 : X76 X65 X6C X6F X70 X65 X3E _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _  | velope>
```

This is exactly the amount of bytes of the second TCP packet !!!

Here is the code of the part of my program handling the SOAP requests :

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include "decap/structs.h"
#include "decap/tcp_threads.h"
#include "gpi_tools.h"
#include "mecevp.h"
#include "smdevp.h"
#include "wsseapi.h"
#include "soapH.h"
#include "MercuriusServiceSoap12.nsmap"
#include "commons.h"

const char  soap_action_find_info[] = "findInfo";
const char  soap_action_find_user[] = "findUser";
const char  *soap_action[] = { soap_action_find_info, soap_action_find_info, soap_action_find_user };

...

int commons_request( tcp_thread *me, char *request, char *soap_endpoint, char *pem_file )
{
    int                             i;
    int                             params_len;
    FILE                            *fd;
    char                            file_spec[192];
    EVP_PKEY                    *rsa_private_key = NULL;
    char                            *indicator_str;
    char                            *requester_language;
    char                            *datetime;
    rt_request_type     request_type;
    time_t                      cur_time;
    time_t                      req_time;
    dom__Indicator      indicator = dom__Indicator__2;
    int                             soap_status;

    specific_datas      *sd = (specific_datas *)me->specific;

    gpi_file_spec( file_spec, pem_file );
    fd = fopen( file_spec, "r" );
    rsa_private_key = PEM_read_PrivateKey( fd, NULL, NULL, (void *)pem_password );
    fclose( fd );
    params_len = (int)strlen( request );
    for( i = 0; i < params_len; i++ )
        if( request[i] == (sd->request_separator) )
            request[i] = (char)0x00;

/* WS Security */
    soap_init2( &(sd->soap), SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE, SOAP_XML_CANONICAL|SOAP_IO_KEEPALIVE );

    (sd->soap).connect_timeout = 10;
    (sd->soap).send_timeout = 15;
    (sd->soap).recv_timeout = 15;
    (sd->soap).transfer_timeout = 30;

    soap_register_plugin( &(sd->soap), soap_wsse );
    soap_wsse_add_Security( &(sd->soap) );
    soap_wsse_add_BinarySecurityTokenPEM( &(sd->soap), "X509Token", file_spec );
    soap_wsse_add_KeyInfo_SecurityTokenReferenceX509( &(sd->soap), "#X509Token" );
    soap_wsse_sign_body( &(sd->soap), SOAP_SMD_SIGN_RSA_SHA1, rsa_private_key, 0 );

/* SSL management */
    soap_ssl_init();
    soap_ssl_client_context( &(sd->soap), SOAP_SSL_DEFAULT, file_spec, pem_password, NULL, NULL, NULL );

/* Building request */

    time( &cur_time );

    (sd->requester).nationalNumber = (char *)requester_national_number[(sd->request_mode)];
    req_time = cur_time;

    switch( toupper( request[0] ) )
    {
        case 'R':
            request_type = rt_nat_nbr;
            break;

        case 'M':
            request_type = rt_mach_site;
            break;

        case 'N':
            request_type = rt_name_birth;
            break;

        default:
            request_type = rt_invalid;
    }

    indicator_str = request + strlen( request ) + 1;
    switch( indicator_str[0] )
    {
        case '0':
            indicator = dom__Indicator__0;
            break;

        case '1':
            indicator = dom__Indicator__1;
            break;

        case '2':
            indicator = dom__Indicator__2;
            break;

        case '3':
            indicator = dom__Indicator__3;
            break;
    }

    requester_language = indicator_str + strlen( indicator_str ) + 1;
    switch( toupper( requester_language[0] ) )
    {
        case 'F':
            (sd->requester).language = com__Language__FR;
            break;
        case 'N':
            (sd->requester).language = com__Language__NL;
            break;
        case 'D':
            (sd->requester).language = com__Language__DE;
            break;
        case 'E':
            (sd->requester).language = com__Language__EN;
            break;
        default:
            (sd->requester).language = com__Language__XX;
    }

    if( request_type == rt_nat_nbr )
    {
        char        *rrn_number;

        rrn_number = requester_language + strlen( requester_language ) + 1;
        datetime = rrn_number + strlen( rrn_number ) + 1;
        if( strlen( datetime ) > 0 )
            req_time = decap_str_to_time_t( datetime, "%Y-%m-%d" );
        (sd->find_info_request).requester = &(sd->requester);
        (sd->find_info_request).criteria = &(sd->info_criteria);
        (sd->info_criteria).__union_InfoCriteria = 1;
        (sd->info_criteria).union_InfoCriteria.nationalNumberCriteria = &(sd->nationalNumberCriteria);
        (sd->nationalNumberCriteria).__union_NationalNumberCriteria = 1;
        (sd->nationalNumberCriteria).union_NationalNumberCriteria.nationalNumber = rrn_number;
        (sd->info_criteria).infoDateTime = req_time;
        (sd->info_criteria).__sizeindicator = 1;
        (sd->info_criteria).indicator = &indicator;
        soap_status = soap_call___mrj__findInfo(    &(sd->soap), soap_endpoint, soap_action[request_type],
                                                                                            &(sd->find_info_request), &(sd->find_info_response) );
    }
    else if( request_type == rt_mach_site )
    {
        char        *mach_id;
        char        *site_id;

        mach_id = requester_language + strlen( requester_language ) + 1;
        site_id = mach_id + strlen( mach_id ) + 1;
        datetime = site_id + strlen( site_id ) + 1;
        if( strlen( datetime ) > 0 )
            req_time = decap_str_to_time_t( datetime, "%Y-%m-%d" );
        (sd->find_info_request).requester = &(sd->requester);
        (sd->find_info_request).criteria = &(sd->info_criteria);
        (sd->info_criteria).__union_InfoCriteria = 2;
        (sd->info_criteria).union_InfoCriteria.machCriteria = &(sd->machCriteria);
        (sd->machCriteria).machId = mach_id;
        (sd->machCriteria).siteId = site_id;
        (sd->info_criteria).infoDateTime = req_time;
        (sd->info_criteria).__sizeindicator = 1;
        (sd->info_criteria).indicator = &indicator;
        soap_status = soap_call___mrj__findInfo(    &(sd->soap), soap_endpoint, soap_action[request_type],
                                                                                            &(sd->find_info_request), &(sd->find_info_response) );
    }
    else if( request_type == rt_name_birth )
    {
        char        *name;
        char        *firstName;
        char        *birthDate;

        name = requester_language + strlen( requester_language ) + 1;
        firstName = name + strlen( name ) + 1;
        birthDate = firstName + strlen( firstName ) + 1;
        datetime = birthDate + strlen( birthDate ) + 1;
        if( strlen( datetime ) > 0 )
            req_time = decap_str_to_time_t( datetime, "%Y-%m-%d" );
        (sd->find_user_request).requester = &(sd->requester);
        (sd->find_user_request).criteria = &(sd->user_criteria);
        (sd->user_criteria).nameCriteria = &(sd->nameCriteria);
        (sd->nameCriteria).name = name;
        (sd->nameCriteria).firstName = firstName;
        (sd->nameCriteria).birthDate = birthDate;
        (sd->user_criteria).infoDateTime = req_time;
        (sd->user_criteria).__sizeindicator = 1;
        (sd->user_criteria).indicator = &indicator;
        soap_status = soap_call___mrj__findUser(    &(sd->soap), soap_endpoint, soap_action[request_type],
                                                                                            &(sd->find_user_request), &(sd->find_user_response) );
    }
    (sd->soap).buf[(sd->soap).buflen] = (char)0x00;

    return( soap_status );
}
```

Could this problem come from bad parameters in "soap_init2" ?

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The message received is saved to RECV.log when the code is compiled in DEBUG mode.

To clarify the buffering scheme, the XML engine of gsoap does not store the entire message received in a buffer. Rather, for performance reasons, the engine and generated code incrementally deserialize inbound messages by reading a block of data at a time. Previous data read is discarded from the buffer.

This is evident when you look at the TEST.log:

```
...
Read 4344 bytes from socket=5/fd=0
Read count=4344 (+4344)
...
Read 999 bytes from socket=5/fd=0
Read count=5343 (+999)
...
```

Each read operation fills the buffer again with minimal blocking. Therefore, the buffer may contain anything, i.e. one or more TCP packets or as little data as a single byte. When you dump the buffer at the end of the message, it only contains the last TCP packet received.

This approach to incremental parsing and deserialization is efficient as the deserializer can start immediately when the first packet arrives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem that I have is that I am just an interface between a SOAP server and a EBCDIC oriented mainframe. I need is to send the XML SOAP answer "as is" (converted in EBCDIC) to this mainframe.

It looks like "soap_call__xxx" can't do that. How can I get the full XML answer ?